# onkeyup event seems to not fire or is ignored

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have this:

```
txtNew.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "alert('hi');");
```

But when I type in the textbox - no alert comes up.  I just type and type and no alert ever comes up.  Why is this not working?

Tried in IE 11, Chrome 42.0, and FF 37.0.  Using .NET 4.0.

Also tried the "`onkeypress`" event.  Same results.  I cannot get the alert to come up.

The textbox definition is:

```
asp:TextBox ID="txtNew" TextMode="Password" runat="server" MaxLength="256
```

Tried removing the TextMode attribute but the result is still the same.

Ultimately, what I want to do is this:

```
txtNew.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "CheckChars()");
```

Where `CheckChars()` is my JS script.  However when it didn't work, I just put an  '`alert()`' in there to see if even that would work.

Comment: Have you looked at the rendered HTML to see if your attribute, in any form, is actually present in the textbox? When are you adding the attribute (in which event handler)?

Comment: Try  txtNew.Attributes["onclick"] ="alert("Hello World")"; Havent tested but should work

Comment: Are you attempting this in the codebehind (from the  .cs page) or as javascript (on the client)?

Comment: This line (attributes.add) is in Page_Load in the codebehind.

Comment: Then run the page again, and inspect the generated code. Look for the textbox that ASP.NET rendered for you and see if your custom attribute is present.

Comment: Hmm.  Ran it again in IE and did a view source.  The attribute is not present for the textbox.  Why would this happen?

Comment: Thanks David W.  Your comment got me thinking and I found the actual issue - there was a problem much further back that eventually prevented the attributes.add from being executed which is why it didn't show up in the page source.

Comment: Great! Glad I was able to help in some way.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just reference the ID of a control to reference it in javascript. You need to actually get a reference to the control using

```
var txtNew = document.getElementById("txtNew");
txtNew.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "alert('hi');");
```

Edit: Actually, is this code in your javascript or in your codebehind? The question is unclear.